# after selecting dropdown it value is showing null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown

in view

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CityId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.CityId"></select>
            </div>
```

in controller

```cs
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> citylist = _context.Cities.Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name.ToString(), Value = u.CityId.ToString() });
       ViewBag.CityId=citylist;
```

Comment: could you pls show us your `model` which contains the `CityId` used in `asp-for="CityId"`, just look weird

Answer (score 0):

> The Select Tag Helper asp-for specifies the model property name for
> the select element and asp-items specifies the option elements

sample like this model

```
public class SelectModel
    {
        public string CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> list { get; set; }
    }

public IActionResult Index()
{
            SelectModel mod = new SelectModel {
                list = new List<SelectListItem> { 
                    new SelectListItem{
                        Text = "City1", Value = "CityId1",Selected = false
                    },
                    new SelectListItem{
                        Text = "City2", Value = "CityId2",Selected = false 
                    },
                    new SelectListItem{
                        Text = "City3",Value = "CityId3",Selected = true 
                    }
                },
            };
            ViewBag.list = mod.list;
            return View(mod);
}
[HttpPost]
public string submitData(SelectModel mod) {
     var id = mod.CityId;
     var name = mod.CityName;//I set <select asp-for="CityId", so name will be null here
            return "choose" + name + "which id is " + id;
}
```

both `asp-items="@ViewBag.list"` and `asp-items="@Model.list"` will work

```
@model WebAppOfoFlow.Models.SelectModel

<form method="post" asp-action="submitData">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="CityName" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.list" style="width:33%"></select>
        @*<select asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.list" style="width:33%"></select>*@
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="push data" />
</form>
```

In your scenario, my suggestion is hard code value for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> citylist` to check if the page can render correctly.

[image]

Comment: i tried all this things but it isshowing  null in model when I post form

Comment: Hi patel, many thanks for your reply, and could you pls share your model so help continue troubleshoot it? or you may take a look at my code snippet, I shared all the codes above.